# Can I read a striped volume (2 HDDs) encrypted with VeraCrypt from another OS or after "PC reset"?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, encryption, truecrypt, veracrypt

So I [created a striped volume](http://www.windowscentral.com/how-create-one-large-volume-using-multiple-hard-drives-windows-10) from 2 hard drives of the same size & type from within a VeraCrypt encrypted system (Windows 10) and encrypted it with VeraCrypt therafter. Now this VeraCrypt encrypted system drive doesn't boot anymore even after perma-decrypting it and I'm not sure if I get it working again.

-> can I read/mount the encrypted striped volume from another OS than the one I created it in?

And also I'd like to try "Reset this PC" from the Windows 10 repair options. Will I still be able to read the striped volume afterwards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So when I connected the disks to another PC where they show up as "Dynamic Foreign" in disk management with the option to "Import Foreign Disks".

However it worked after I reset my PC with which I set up the striped volume. For this I first perma-decrypted my system volume encrypted with VeraCrypt using the rescue USB stick.
I could still not reset my PC at first but I executed a few statements (such as chkdsk; Google it) in the repair console after which it worked.

It also still worked after I formatted my system drive and reinstalled Windows 10 64Bit to it.

Answer (score 0):

Its difficult to comment for certain without more knowledge of your specific setup, but in general -
* It would be a bad idea to "Reset this PC" if you want to recover data from the drives in the computer.

- If you have a striped volume, you will need both disks to get the data off it.  Depending on how the striping was done, you may be able to use another OS, but this is not likely (using a newer or older version of the OS stands a much better chance then trying to use Linux for example.

You should look at the disk as a number of layers.   You have 2 physical disks each with partitions.  You then have combined the partitions into a single block device (volume) which you then encrypted.    If you can use your original OS to see the volume, you could then bit copy that volume onto a partition - even if its encrypted - and mount/open it in another OS which can recognise that partition with Veracrypt.

Comment: The "reset this PC" function has one variant that "keeps personal data but not settings and apps", also it should only reset the (connected) system drive and not the (unconnected) striped volume. I created the striped volume as in the tutorial I linked. Will it work if I freshly install Windows 10 on my system drive or connect those 2 drives to another PC with Windows 10?

Comment: Sorry, I am not willing to risk providing a wrong answer and costing you your data.   I do not use Windows much (I'm a Linux sysadmin).   I can say that removing the drives, installing Windows then plugging the drives in and seeing if they are recognised is a much safer bet.

Comment: That's understandable. So now I connected the 2 drives to another PC where they show up as "Dynamic Foreign" and I'm not sure how to proceed and whether's safe to do "Import Foreign Disks" without losing/corrupting the encrypted data.